# WiX Burn bootstrapper does not uninstall MSI package

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn

I have created a Wix Burn boostrapper that successfully installs all of the chained packages. When I run uninstall, it doesn't uninstall the following MSI package. Why? Also, I realized this question has been asked, but none of the previously asked questions seem to have answers.

```
<MsiPackage Id="SyncManager" Name="Sync Manager 2.0" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" Compressed="yes"
              DownloadUrl="http://localhost/SyncManager2.0.msi" SourceFile="SyncManager2.0.msi">
    <Payload DownloadUrl="http://localhost/SyncManager2.0.msi" SourceFile="SyncManager2.0.msi" Name="Synce Manager 2.0" />
</MsiPackage>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you have `Permanent="yes"`

Comment: Thank you. I new it was something simple.

Comment: I confirm it worked even if documentation says default value is "no" I had to make it explicit with Permanent="no"